# the map to show rs image have a bug. the topright layercontrol has the image name, but don't show in the map?

Tags: python, ipyleaflet

as the title contents, the image url transmit to ipyleaflet.TileLayer method and return a tilelayer use to self.add_layer(tilelayer), use mode to show a image in the map, the part code following:

to run code show map

he map topright have a layercontrol and 'imagelayer' is the above contents image name, but the map don't the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if response:
        _data = response.get("data", {})
        _id = _data.get("id")
        _url = _data.get("url")
        kwargs = {
            "url": _url,
            "name": name
        }
   imagelayer = basemap_to_tiles(kwargs)
   self.add_layer(imagelayer)
```